# Regex to match a string if it matches only one group in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I would like to know, is there a regex that could help match
text, only if the tested string belongs only to one of the tested groups?

let's say I have these two groups:

Group 1: `[a-zA-Z]`

Group 2: `[0-9]`

So is there an applicable regex, to match only the following string: `abc`,
or only this one: `123`.

But that **would not match anything**, when there is a string that represents a combination of both groups, i.g: `123abc2b`?

P.S: I'm using Java.

Comment: `String#matches` and use `^...$` to delimit the boundaries of your `String`

Comment: Could you please provide a specific use example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternation is key to your problem. Use pattern `^(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z]*)$`

Explnation:

`^` - beginning of the string

`(?:...)` - non-captruing group

`\d*`- match zero or more digits

`|` - alternation

`[a-zA-Z]*` - match zero or more letters (lower or uppercase)

`$` - match end of the string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MCfO9C/1)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn your answer is spot on, as Haim is new to Regular Expressions, and keeping with his thought pattern. Check for multiple instances of group one [a-zA-Z] by adding a + or multiple instances of group two [0-9] by adding a +. The or is denoted by pipe resulting in ([a-zA-Z]+)|([0-9]+). Which will work in Java. However the answer here is more complete.

Comment: @HaimLvov have a look at this page for more info. https://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, I think you just need `|`, which means "or" in regex. To match either `[a-zA-Z]` *or* `[0-9]`, but not both.

e.g.

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)$
```